# How to i insert foreign key to my database table

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two table having relationship but when I do send data into database I got `NULL`, I am using Vuejs with Laravel normally in laravel I may use foreach loop to do so but I am a beginner with laravel & Vuejs

My two tables are students and parent, I have a foreign key at student table that references parent id

Anyone one who can help me how go through this

My problem is when i send data the foreign key at student table is inserted as NULL

This is my student model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'pregistration_id',
    'admission_no',
    'fname',
    'mname',
    'lname',
    'dob',
    'gender',
    'primary_school',
    'form_enrolled',
    'transfered_from',
    'transfered_to',
];
```

This is my parent model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'fname',
    'mname',
    'lname',
    'residence',
    'phone',
    'occupation',
];
```

This is my student controller:

```
return Student::create([
    'pregistration_id'=>$request['pregistration_id'],
    'admission_no'=>$request['admission_no'],
    'fname'=>$request['fname'],
    'mname'=>$request['mname'],
    'lname'=>$request['lname'],
    'dob'=>$request['dob'],
    'gender'=>$request['gender'],
    'primary_school'=>$request['primary_school'],
    'form_enrolled'=>$request['form_enrolled'],
    'transfered_from'=>$request['transfered_from'],
    'transfered_to'=>$request['transfered_to'],
    // dd($request->all())
]);
```

This is my students table:

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('pregistration_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->integer('admission_no')->unique();
    $table->string('fname');
    $table->string('mname');
    $table->string('lname');
    $table->date('dob');
    $table->string('gender');
    $table->string('primary_school');
    $table->string('form_enrolled');
    $table->string('transfered_from');
    $table->string('transfered_to');
    $table->foreign('pregistration_id')->references('id')->on('pregistrations');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is a part of student component in Vue:

```
data() {
  return {
    editmode: false,
    students: {},
    form: new Form({
      id: '',
      admission_no: '',
      fname: '',
      mname: '',
      lname: '',
      dob: '',
      gender: '',
      primary_school: '',
      form_enrolled: '',
      trasfered_from:'',
      trasfered_to: ''
    })
  }
},
```

Comment: Did you create a model for student and parent both and have specified all the table columns in fillable variable For example:
`protected $fillable = ['id','name','gender'];`

Comment: Yes i created the model for both student and parent with $fillable

Comment: Edit your question and post your code that you tried, It'll be easy for us to help you

Comment: In case if you receive all values NULL, Please check, as you have used `$request` , have you assigned your incoming data to `$request`. I mean have you added this line `$request = $request->all()`

Comment: I have added this line $request = $request->all() but still it send a NULL data to database

Comment: Do you get any error? check console as well

Comment: Please check if your form is actually sending the data you want to store. You can do this by die dumping (dd) or var dumping (var_dump) the request variables.